# joomla component error

Tags: joomla

I have installed a joomla component and its working quite good but i am facing the problem that whenever i am trying to send mail by using the component iam always getting the message
"Could not instantiate mail function."

Please help me in getting the solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

It could not find any valid setting in your configuration.php for sending out e-mail.
The settings you should check in configuration are the ones prefixed with '$smtp'.

On the other hand, if you installed a 3rd party component, check if they implemented the send email function in a proper way; meaning that e-mails are sent using the mail routines provided by the framework (phpmailer) rather than a custom mail implementation.